# CSS - repeat a before insert every nth ajacent element

Tags: html, css

I have a structure such as :

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='half-screen'></div>
    <div class='half-screen'></div>
    <div class='half-screen'></div>
    <div class='half-screen'></div>
</div>
```

I have to add divs dynamically and I'm wondering if there's a way to create the relationship dynamically so that a bar is inserted before every two divs with the half-screen class, i.e. before every 2n+1 div.half-screen.

There may be other ways to restructure and use css for top-border on each half screen but I'm curious to know if I can solve this using the + css adjacent operator

```
 .container {
  &.half-screen + .half-screen + .half-screen {

    &:before {
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
      display:block;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with 2n+1 and :before, just missing a couple steps, unless I'm misunderstanding. Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```css
.half-screen:nth-child(2n+1):before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='half-screen'>1</div>
    <div class='half-screen'>2</div>
    <div class='half-screen'>3</div>
    <div class='half-screen'>4</div>
    <div class='half-screen'>5</div>
    <div class='half-screen'>6</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

I know you're thinking `.a + .a + .a` matches the third element with a class of `a`, but keep in mind it also matches the fourth element with a class of `a`. CSS doesn't really say "Oh, we already used that element for this selector, we won't use it again."